# problema de puertos

Tags: cmd, docker

poseo un problema al ejecutar el comando:

```
docker run --name AAAAA --hostname=DESKTOP-RG1J2JO--privileged=true -t -i -p 8888:8888 -p 8090:80 -p 7180:7180 -p 8020:8020 -p 8088:8088 -p 50070:50070 -p 9093:9083 -p 2525:25 -p 8032:8032 -p 3306:3306 -d 5c4b29cd90de /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

En la cmd esta fue ejecutada como administrador, con privilegios de administrador dando el siguiente error:

> Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   connectivity on endpoint AAAAA
>   (d07560db8c9a32e13874af5fa09d104deb760bf1318b0fec0140384d343cd6bb):
>   Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:50070: bind: Intento
>   de acceso a un socket no permitido por sus permisos de acceso.

Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo estaria muy agradecido.

Comment: Hola, qué imagen estás usando ?
Asegurate que ese puerto esta libre, quizás lo esté usando otro problema, tratá de cambiar ese por otro número, ej: 8899:50070

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que estás usando un [puerto efímero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puertos_ef%C3%ADmeros). Por eso te dice que no se tiene permisos de acceso. Intenta, como te dice @FacundoDiazCobos, utilizando uno menor.

Answer (score 2):

Me he encontrado con el mismo problema, y es debido a que Microsoft reserva una serie de puertos para Hyper-V. Aquí encontré la explicación: [Explicación del porqué del problema y esquema de solución](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/1002)

Los pasos que seguí para solucionarlo son estos tres:

> the steps are:
>
> ```
> Disable hyper-v (which will required a couple of restarts)
> `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`
>
> When you finish all the required restarts, reserve the port you want so hyper-v doesn't reserve it back
> `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=50051 numberofports=1`
>
> Re-Enable hyper-V (which will require a couple of restart)
> `dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All`
> ```
>
> when your system is back, you will be able to bind to that port
>   successfully.

Los saqué de este [comentario](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-459205576), hay que tener en cuenta que en el parámetro del comando startport= debes poneer el puerto que te da error. En mi caso fueron dos, primero el 50070 y luego el 50075.

A mi me funcionó, espero que ayude.